# Как убрать действие :hover для псевдоэлемента :after?

Tags: css, css3, hover

Друзья, есть элементы списка для которых действует псевдокласс `:hover`. Маркеры для этого списка созданы при помощи псевдоэлемента `:after`. Проблема в том, что при наведении курсора на псевдоэлемент работает `:hover` для элемента списка. Как это можно исправить?

```css
.main_menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
.main_menu li:hover {
  color: #ffe600;
}
.main_menu li:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #ffe600;
  top: 10px;
  right: -15px;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main_menu">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Services</li>
  <li>Work</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Приведите минимальный пример, воспроизводящий проблему, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Flash652/yofozpwp/

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" (Ctrl+M) для добавления кода прямо в вопрос. Сообщение должно быть самодостаточным, ссылки на JSFiddle и подобные ресурсы могут служить только дополнением.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Псевдоэлемент `:after` лежит внутри своего родителя, поэтому, это то же самое, если внутрь `li` положить `span, p, a` или какой-либо другой элемент. Для того, чтобы проигнорировать всплытие, необходимо добавить к `:after` свойство `pointer-events:none`.

```css
.main_menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
.main_menu li:hover {
  color: #ffe600;
}
.main_menu li:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #ffe600;
  top: 10px;
  right: -15px;
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main_menu">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Services</li>
  <li>Work</li>
</ul>
```

Результат - [здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/yofozpwp/1/)

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" (Ctrl+M) для добавления кода. Сообщение должно быть самодостаточным, ссылки на JSFiddle и подобные ресурсы могут служить только дополнением.

Comment: @Umer: Единственное замечание [IE11+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events).

Comment: То есть в более младших IE работать не будет? Это как-то можно вылечить?

Answer (score 2):

Псевдо-элемент `::after` является частью элемента и полностью разделяет его псевдо-классы в обе стороны, поэтому `:hover` по определению будет действовать в любой области элемента.

Однако вы слишком упростили разметку. В более реалистичной ситуации меню будет содержать ссылки. В этом случае проблем не возникает: подсветка на ссылках, псевдо-элементы на элементах списка.

```css
.main_menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.main_menu li a {
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 75px;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.main_menu li a:hover {
  color: #ffe600;
}
.main_menu li:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #ffe600;
  top: 10px;
  right: -17px;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main_menu">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
</ul>
```